# Android multiple lines and ellipsize not working with Textview

Tags: android

To resolved multiple lines and ellipsize required of TextView.

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_item_text_view"
    style="@style/ControllerWidget.TextView.SpinnerDropDownItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:singleLine="false" />
```

Solution: Get the text content bound of TextView and invoke TextUtils.ellipsize method to get adjusted string that didn't overflow.

```
fun ellipsize(
    textView: TextView,
    originText: CharSequence,
    maxLines: Int,
    truncateAt: TruncateAt
): CharSequence {
    // left, top, right, bottom
    val compoundDrawables = textView.compoundDrawables
    var compoundWidth = 0
    if (compoundDrawables.isNotEmpty()) {
        if (compoundDrawables[0] != null) {
            compoundWidth += textView.compoundDrawablePadding + compoundDrawables[0].intrinsicWidth
        }
        if (compoundDrawables.size > 2 && compoundDrawables[2] != null) {
            compoundWidth += textView.compoundDrawablePadding + compoundDrawables[2].intrinsicWidth
        }
    }
    val availableWidth =
        textView.width - textView.paddingEnd - textView.paddingStart - compoundWidth
    val textWidth = getMeasureText(textView, originText.toString())
    // occupied lines actually.
    val occupiedLines = (textWidth + availableWidth - 1).toInt() / availableWidth
    // > 1 line.
    if (occupiedLines > 1) {
        // the resolved lines. <= max lines
        val resolvedLines = min(occupiedLines, maxLines)
        return TextUtils.ellipsize(
            originText,
            textView.paint,
            min(availableWidth * resolvedLines.toFloat(), textWidth),
            truncateAt
        )
    }
    return originText
}

private fun getMeasureText(textView: TextView, text: String): Float {
    return textView.paint.measureText(text)
}
```

hope this code can save your.

Comment: Remove ellipssize and max lines from text view widgets.

Comment: @DhruvSakariya thank your, but it can resolve ellipsize = "middle" case?

Comment: yes it can resolve

Comment: @DhruvSakariya Requirements include limiting max number of lines. Which as far as I know cannot be done.